# "Pecking of" or "Pecking on"

Tags: phrase-usage, predicate-frames

Good evening, I am in the midst of completing a poem and wrote the following line:

"The Owl halts its pecking of sweet-fruit"

My question is: would it be correct to say "its pecking of sweet-fruit" or "its pecking on sweet-fruit" etc.

I am just subtly confused on what word you would correctly and most harmoniously use.

Comment: Is there an owl that eats fruit?

Comment: Right, owls are obligate carnivores. And they have hooked beaks so they can't peck either.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you mean it’s or its? Seems that you are referring to pecking being done by the owl so the possessive pronoun “its” is what you want, no?

In regard to the pecking, it should be either “pecking on” or “pecking at” in this context. If necessary you could even say, “... pecking sweet fruit.”

Comment: Owls are carnivorous - they don't eat fruit.

Comment: Oooops, that's true! Maybe try, "The Owl halts its pecking at the vole."

Comment: Thank you most sincerely for the insight, I decided to go with "pecking on"              P.S. just for intrigue-sake, the line "pecks on sweet-fruit" is an absurdist line since, as you have so kindly regarded, the Owl would not have pecked on it on the first place. It is a topsy-turvy like poem.